# Associated Model class not being saved keeps returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a `User` model inside my `Ticket` model but every time I try and set the `User` inside the `Ticket` model, it always just ends up being `null` when I try and retrieve it later on and I cannot seem to figure out why.

The goal is to be able to create a `Ticket`, when creating you can type in a username to associate this ticket to someone. If the user is found, the ticket is created.

However, it does not seem to save the associated `User` that was typed in or any information regarding it.

### Models

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public User owningUser { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
   
    public List<Ticket> assignedTickets { get; set; }
}
```

### Create.razor

```
<InputText id="title" @bind-Value="@ticketItem.owningUser.Username" class="form-control" aria-label="Disabled input example" />

private Ticket ticketItem { get; set; } = new Ticket();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    ticketItem.owningUser = new User();
}

public async Task CreateNewTodoItem()
{
    var result = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("TodoItems", ticketItem);
}
```

### Controller

```
public async Task <ActionResult> CreateNewTodoItem(Ticket item)
    {
        ApplicationUser userValid;
        User tempUser = new User();
        try
        {
            userValid = userManager.Users.Where(s => s.Email == item.owningUser.Username).First();

            item.owningUser = new User();
            item.owningUser.Username = userValid.Email;

            context.Tickets.Add(item);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return NoContent();

        } catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
```

### Retrieval method

```
private User associatedUser { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    ticketItem = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Ticket>($"TodoItems/{Id}");
    associatedUser = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<User>($"User/{Id}");

    ticketItem.owningUser = associatedUser;
}

// Controller ---

[HttpGet("{ticketID}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUserForTicket(Guid ticketID)
    {
        var ticketUser = context.Tickets.First(p => p.Id == ticketID);
        User use = new User { Username = ticketUser.owningUser.Username };
        return Ok(use);
    }
```

### Null error

[image]

### DBContext

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Krellex, what is your `ApiAuthorizationDbContext`? Please debug your code and check if the ticketUser contains value for owningUser, also check it in database.

Answer (score 0):

you have to include owningUser

```
var ticketUser = context.Tickets.Include(o=> o.owningUser).First(p => p.Id == ticketID);

if(ticketUser.owningUser!=null)
 return new User { Username = ticketUser.owningUser.Username };

 return BadRequest("no owningUser");
```

But it can be that owningUser is null or your dbcontext is not configured properly since I can see that your Create action doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but the same null error seems to appear

Comment: Thanks for the further change. The error remains but like you mentioned it the owningUser is likely null because it's not being saved. I'm not sure why it does not seem to save the associated user. I have edited the post above to show by ApplicationDBContext